# Android TextView default line spacing

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

There is a methods that multiply spacing between lines in TextView

- lineSpacingMultiplier

I want to multiply it by 2 , but what is the default spacing value that it multiplies? 2px, 5px?

Thanks.

Comment: the default value is `1.0f`

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt but i asked what size of the gap between two lines in pixels or any other dimention and not the default value of the multiplier with float.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value is a 17.1 percent of the text size.

But use 20 percent to be sure that letter like j or g appear correctly

Comment: Can you please add a reference from Android documentation about "The value is a 17.1 percent of the text size."?

Comment: there isn't. Is just try and test.

Comment: Android is open source. Even if it's not in the documentation, we should be able to link to the code that specifies it.

Answer (score 2):

After some messing around with Spans, I finally found how to find the default line spacing (the space from the lowest glyph (y) in a line to the tallest glyph (L) in the next line). Here is the code:

```
public static int getLineSpacing(TextView textContainer){
    Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetrics = textContainer.getPaint().getFontMetricsInt();
    return fontMetrics.ascent - fontMetrics.top;
}
```